# How to convert integer to byte in Objective-C

Tags: java, objective-c

I have an integer value 190. How can I convert it to byte code?

I do it in Java like this: `a, b, c, d` are integer values:

```
someArray[0] = (byte) a;
someArray[1] = (byte) b;
someArray[2] = (byte) c;
someArray[3] = (byte) d;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If n is integer,then we can convert into byte and add into nsmutabledata like below.

```
NSMutableData *byteData = [NSMutableData new];
[byteData appendBytes:&n length:1];
```